# nginx map request and return with no effect

Tags: nginx, rewrite

i want to rewrite/return request to  new one

i have

- map

  ```
  map $request $new_request {
      include url_rmap.conf;
  }
  ```
- file url_rmap.conf

  ```
  #here i have tried  all variations
  $scheme://d.dom https://any.other/address
  $scheme://d.dom/ https://any.other/address
  https://d.dom https://any.other/address
  https://d.dom/ https://any.other/address
  ```
- server block

  ```
  server {

       listen ip:port;
       server_name a.dom b.dom aa.a.dom w.c.dom d.dom;

       # first try 
       if($new_request) {
             return 301 $new_request;
       }

       # also second with @redirect-nap
       location / {
          # Support Clean (aka Search Engine Friendly) URLs
          try_files  @redirect-map $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
       }

       location @redirect-map {
            if ($new_request) {  # redirect if the variable is defined
                  return 301 $new_request;
            }
       }

  }
  ```

both ways with call to https://d.dom  fails to redirect / no effect why ?

*Why are you trying to map on $request? – Michael Hampton♦*

> *i can count so many....  reasons*

1) because i can ??? almost can ? 
2) i want to change external ugly url like:

```
   https://shitgoogle.com/saome.stupidaddres/c/ssss/11232354256goofle
```

to my subdomain:

```
  https://gc.dom.com   :)
```

and the second one:

2) is short
3) is nice 
4) is whatever i want 
5) independent 
5) *is mine !!!* 
6) etc...

besides that name and services are bound

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong variable.

You're trying to `map` on the `$request` variable, which does not do what you say you want.

This variable, as documented, contains the entire request line from the HTTP request. For instance:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

To match the URL the user used, you would first have to reconstruct it. No single variable contains this information. For example:

```
map $scheme://$host$request_uri $new_request {
```

And that still might not be the best way of doing ... whatever you're doing.

Comment: request :you mean heders + body (as per post ?)  or get request => as url + query string  -> http://gc.dom.com?a=1&x ....   (url without headers?) - there is no doc explanation what is  what - enigmatic request or host  .. ? what is host host as per http v1.1 spec ? i deal with sockets and raw request in java so i know what is raw reqest

Comment: can you give me example how rewrite url - > https://gc.domain.com to  other url -> http://second.domain.net/someuri&t=1 with map directive and server bloc taking in consideration that server  is listening on ip:443 has server_names  dor certain domains and subdomains and rewriting every request from  ip:80 to ip:443 (without touching .well-know location )